# Django "ajax-CRUD-tutorial", "NoReverseMatch" on update customer

Tags: ajax, django, crud

So I have been working on this ajax CRUD tutorial from [Simple is better than complex: How to Implement CRUD Using Ajax and Json](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html)

Event though I can get the "create" part of the CRUD working with ajax, I get stuck at the "update part".

To update data for a customer I need to retrieve the "customer.id" and pass it to the url.

In the tutorial described above we use the action of the form with an argument for the book.id, or in my case customer.id.

When I use a direct customer id, for example #72, the view works ok but when I try to use form.instance.pk, I get a NoReverseMatch error.

```
Reverse for 'customer_update_modal' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['customer/(?P<pk>\\d+)/update/$']
```

How should i put the customer.id into the argument to get the wanted result?

## partial_customer_update.html

```
<form class="form-on-card--modal modal-trigger js-customer-update-form" action="{% url 'customer_update_modal' form.instance.pk %}" method="POST" novalidate>
```

## views.py

```
def save_customer_form(request, form, template_name):
data = dict()
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        customers = Customer.objects.all()[:10]
        data['html_show_all_customers'] = render_to_string('includes/partial_customer_list.html',
            {'customer_list': customers}
        )
    else:
        data['form_is_valid'] = False

context = {'form': form}
data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
return JsonResponse(data)


def customer_create(request):# Function based view to create a new customer
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
else:
    form = CustomerForm()
return save_customer_form(request, form, 'includes/partial_customer_create.html')


def customer_update(request, pk):
customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=pk)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CustomerForm(request.POST, instance=customer)
else:
    form = CustomerForm(instance=customer)
return save_customer_form(request, form, 'includes/partial_customer_update.html')
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns += [  # Links to create, update and delete customers
url(r'^customer/create/$', login_required(views.customer_create), name='customer_create_modal'), # Function based view, mind the "as_view()"
url(r'^customer/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', login_required(views.customer_update), name='customer_update_modal'),
```

]

Comment: The `customer_update` instantiates the form with `instance=customer` so it shouldn't give that error when rendering `partial_customer_update.html`. Double check that it is that view/template which is causing the error.

Comment: Can you confirm that the browser is definitely sending a POST request when you press the Update Customer button? You should be able to see that from looking at the network tab in developer tools in your browser.

Comment: Once I use "customer.pk" instead of "form.instance.pk" it does view correctly. When I update the form I get a response "[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 48ms], the response payload: NoReverseMatch at /customer/108/update/
Reverse for 'customer_update_modal' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['customer/(?P<pk>\\d+)/update/$']

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I've found the little bastard.

Even though I wanted to show the "partial_customer_update.html" this template was never loaded. I had the "partial_customer_create.html" hardcoded in the template.

This means that whenever I tried to update the form, it still triggered the "partial_customer_create.html" template.